# Is there any use case for mongodb two-sided relationship?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query

I see many opinions online including [mongodb's own docs](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design), saying declaring a two sided relationship/reference in mongodb can optimize read queries on the has_many side, eg:

```
// psuedo code for brevity
// user has many tasks
tasks: [objectId()]

// task belong to user
userId: ObjectId
```

The "selling point" of including `tasks: []` reference on the user collection is an optimized query to get all user tasks:

```
// psuedo code for brevity
user.populate("tasks")
```

What I don't understand is, why lose atomic updates + increase write complexity, when we can just index the tasks collection based on user id, and just do:

```
// psuedo code for brevity
tasks,find({userId: user._id})
```

In today's world indexing is very simple and cheap to do, so am I missing something extremely basic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> indexing is very simple and cheap to do

Simple - yes, cheap - no. Indexes use RAM and require actualisation after write operations.

> am I missing something

only scale. On few GB db you will be better off with simplified app logic as you suggested. One of mongo's selling point is it **allows** to optimise data structure to make **specific queries** very efficient eve on multi-TB clusters. At the cost of data denormalization, and more complex app logic, pre-aggregations etc.

In earlier versions of mmapv1 storage engine you had to consider how data is physically stored in the file system to get the most from the DB. WiredTiger took care about most of it, so less of a hassle now. Keep in mind you are referring to an 8 years-old article. Although the philosophy didn't change, practical recipes may need some adjustment. E.g. there were great improvements in handling time-series data, so you may not need complex preaggregations.

The main idea is to be aware about possible ways of optimisation, not necessarily use all of them simultaneously in your particular case.

Comment: I understand indexes require actualisation after write ops, but having a two sided referenced relationship requires that as well, in addition to have to handle consistent data on both ends, but maybe it's cheaper?

Comment: may be =) see, SQL dbs had relation algebra developed 100 years before first computer. mongo does not. it's a tool to build scalable solutions focused on performance and availability for specific usecases. there is no best solution for all problems. now, index is a b-tree, and its performance degrades at scale. refs within a document solves this problem, as it performs at the same speed regardless of db size. and yes, at the cost of increased complexity of writes on app level to ensure data integrity. let me stress again, if indexes suffice for you - use them, it is simpler indeed.

Comment: At this point indexes suffice, but soon they might not be. So after reading about [`b-tree`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#B-tree_usage_in_databases) (thanks for the education!), what I still don't get is: the `_id` is also an index, so it will suffer the same scale issues no?

Comment: _"but soon they might not be"_ - that's why you need to test. Extrapolate size of the dataset, populate the test cluster with mgodatagen, run your queries, play with indices to make it futureproof. As I said there are too many factors to consider theorizing, so I always recommend test-driven approach.  _"id is also an index"_ yes, but it's unavoidable. the more indexes you add the more overhead.  Don't get me wrong - indices are good, it's just they might not be good enough in some edge cases. Don't solve a problem until you prove it exists.

Comment: @AlexBlex you are statue of wisdom